# How to get user profiles in linkedin using ROR+omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, linkedin-api

I have successfully verified the linkedin credentials using omniauth and it also redirects to my application with verifier and token, using this how to get user profile information from linkedin and what are all information we can get from this?

Please help as i am new guy to ROR.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you achieved what you asked for? I am wondering the same. I need to get as much as info from linked in. Currently using [this gem](https://github.com/decioferreira/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2) for linkedin access, but it can only fetch basic information. How to get most information out of linkedin. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinkedIn has a *REST api* so you have two solutions:

- Build yourself the requests you need according to [the documentation](http://developer.linkedin.com/apis) (there you will find all information you can get).

  To make the HTTP requests I recommend you the gem [HTTParty](http://httparty.rubyforge.org/) which allows you to automatically parse XML or JSON responses.
- Use an already-made wrapper like the [linkedin gem](https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin).